# How to save images on other platforms to save space on system to optimize website?

Tags: web, optimization, storage, azure-storage, firebase-storage

I am creating a website that allows users to post news, photos, videos...

My database is roughly like this:

`PostNews_M` table has a column named `ImgID`, this column is foreign key to the table `Image_M (ImgID, Link)`.

I think if the site has fewer users with little post, every post has little images, so the images stored on the server does not problem matter.

But if one day the website has more users, the storage of such image will have problems, it will cause the server to store more images, the website will be heavy and slow.

I think that when the user posts the post, the image will be saved in another place, then column `Link` will save the url of the image, so when i load the website, system will call the image url has been saved in the `Link`.

I am looking forward to have someone suggest, advice me how to handle or how to give me keyword to me to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you could use **Azure Blob Storage** to do it.

Azure Blob Storage can be used to store several kinds of files, including news, photos, videos. If you store the files you need to blob, each of them will have a **URL**. Then you could save the url to column `Link`.You can find them in the **portal** or **Azure Storage Explorer**.

- In the portal

[image]

- In the Azure Storage Explorer

[image]

For more details, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction).