# store images and media in azure

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, azure-sql-database

I was developing rest api using asp.net web api 2 and ado.net, I'm already done and i know all the concept, but now i want to move to cloud (azure) instead my local server, i migrated all sql data, but im confused how can i store files(images) in azure sql to retrieve them

any suggestion how can i start to end up with something like this

```
[
{
    "pK_ID": 1,
    "name_EN": "John",
    "count": 0,
    "phone": "52525",
    "image": "/john.png"
}]
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you plan to store files, please consider using Cosmos DB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, if we store the images in azure database, it will be unreasonable. I think you could use **Azure Blob Storage** to do it.

**Azure Blob Storage** can be used to store several kinds of files, including news, files, photos, videos, etc. If you store the files you need to blob, each of them will have a **URL**.

Then you could store it like

`"image": "https://teststorage.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/john.png"`.

- You can find them in the **portal** or **Azure Storage Explorer**, please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954605/how-to-save-images-on-other-platforms-to-save-space-on-system-to-optimize-websit/49976863#49976863).
- For more details about **Azure Blob Storage**, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction).

Comment: I have read it but, how can i start developing web api 2 with ado .net and connect to azure blob

Comment: @ahmed You could refer to [Get started with Azure Blob storage and Visual Studio connected services (ASP.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/visual-studio/vs-storage-aspnet-getting-started-blobs#prerequisites)